# get prime numbers and total prime numbers in range

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java. I am writing this program to show all prime numbers in between the number supplied from the user.

Current output is:

```
2, 3, 5, 7, Count: 4
```

But, i want the output to be like:

`"The number of prime is: "+count+", and they are: " followed by all the numbers separated by comma`

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
                .println("Enter the number till which the prime numbers are to be calculated: ");
        int input = scanner.nextInt();

        int count = 0;

        // loop through the numbers one by one
        for (int i = 2; i < input; i++) {

            boolean isPrimeNumber = true;

            // check to see if the number is prime
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    isPrimeNumber = false;
                    break; // exit the inner for loop
                }
            }

            // print the number if prime
            if (isPrimeNumber) {
                count++;
                System.out.print(i + ", ");

            }

        }
        System.out.println("Count: " + count);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to store the values, for example like this :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PrimeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number till which the prime numbers are to be calculated: ");
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();

        // loop through the numbers one by one
        for (int i = 2; i < input; i++) {
            boolean isPrimeNumber = true;

            // check to see if the number is prime
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    isPrimeNumber = false;
                    break; // exit the inner for loop
                }
            }

            // print the number if prime
            if (isPrimeNumber) {
                primes.add(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number of prime is: " + primes.size() + ", and they are: " + primes.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it will be called "inside", it is better to know, for beginners, what methods are used implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you every one for helping out.

My final code:

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PrimeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number till which the prime numbers are to be calculated: ");
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close();
        List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();

        // loop through the numbers one by one (edit include input in range)
        for (int i = 2; i <= input; i++) {
            boolean isPrimeNumber = true;

            // check to see if the number is prime
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    isPrimeNumber = false;
                    break; // exit the inner for loop
                }
            }

            // print the number if prime
            if (isPrimeNumber) {
                primes.add(i);
            }
        }
        String s = primes.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
        System.out.println("The number of prime is: " + primes.size() + ", and they are: " + s);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the number till which the prime numbers are to be calculated: 70
The number of prime is: 19, and they are: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the primes in an array and display them at the end, outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Save the generated prime numbers into a List and generate the output in the end. For example:

```
System.out.println("The number of prime is: " + list.size());
foreach(int prime : list)
    System.out.print(prime + ", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing a new found prime (`System.out.print(i + ", ");`), store it in a list (`primes.add(i)`), and display this list at the end of your program. Your list must be declared outside your `for` loop (`List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>()`;).

Answer (score 0):

**Get prime numbers and total prime numbers in range**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ListPrimeNumbers {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws NumberFormatException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        int count=0;
        int limit;

        System.out.println("Enter the Limit:");

        InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);

        limit = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        System.out.println("Prime numbers From 1 to " + limit);

        //loop from 1 to limit
        for(int i=1; i < limit; i++) {

            boolean isPrime = true;

            //check to see if the number is prime
            for(int j=2; j < i ; j++) {

                if(i % j == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // print the number
            if(isPrime) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nTotal Prime Number in given range: "+count);
    }

}
```

**Output:**

Enter the Limit:

10

Prime numbers From 1 to 10

1 2 3 5 7

Total Prime Number in given range: 5

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource (that I removed here) may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/advertising).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one that lists and count the prime numbers between 1 and any given number without using any boolean. May be you find it interesting.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int limit = 30; // The program will show prime numbers between 1 and this limit.
        System.out.println("Prime numbers between 1 and "+limit+" (except the number 2) :");
        System.out.println();
        int amount=1; // The amount will give how many prime numbers exist between the interval.

        for (int dividend =2; dividend <=limit; dividend++) {

            for (int divider=2; divider< dividend; divider++) {
                int remaining = dividend % divider;
                if (remaining==0){
                    break;
                }

                if (divider==dividend-1) {
                    // If the loop manages to come here without having broken, then the dividend a prime number.
                    System.out.println(dividend + " IS A PRIME NUMBER.");

                    amount++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("There are a total of "+amount+" prime numbers between 1 and "+limit+" including the number 2. ");
    }
}
```

Comment: The output of this program is a bit different than what's required in the answer. As an idea I would extract your code within a function and return the prime numbers in a collection - then you can easily build the output :)

Comment: OK. You are free. :) Yes, since it prints on the screen without recording into a list, the console of IntelliJ cannot show all the numbers when the list is big. And a small reminder; it took my i7 laptop 17 minutes to count and list prime numbers between 1 and 1.000.000. So, some optimization is needed I think. Anyway, it was just one trial and when I realised that it is also possible without using boolean, I thought some may find it interesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 

    {

        int i,high=10 , low=2,flag ,count=0 ;

        

        while (low<high)

        {

            flag=0;

            for (i=2;i<=low/2;i++)

            {

                if (low%i==0)

                {

                    flag=1;

                    break;

                }

            }

            if (flag==0)

            {       

                System.out.println(low);

            count++;

        }

            ++low;

            

        }

        

    System.out.println("Total number are: "+count);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class PrimeNumbersInRange {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
             int lb = 0, ub = 20;
             List<Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(lb,ub)
                               .filter(PrimeNumbersInRange::isPrime)
                               .boxed()
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println(list);
            System.out.println(list.size());
      }

      public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
        if (num < 2 || (num > 2 && num % 2 == 0)) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
            if (num % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
 }
```