# Prime Number in java

Tags: java

I wrote some code to find prime numbers up to a given number. Could you guys let me know ways to make my code more efficient or better? Or give insight on how I did? In addition, there is a problem in my code where certain numbers repeats twice or three times in a pattern. How do I fix this?

```
public class PrimeNumber2 {

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      int max_prime = 10000;
      for(int i = 3; i < max_prime; i+=2)
      {
         for(int j = 1; j < Math.sqrt(i); j++)
         {
            if(i % j == 0)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }

     }

   }    
}
```

Comment: Use debugger to understand what happens in your code!

Comment: Don't use `Math.sqrt(i)` so. Extract it into a variable because this is a very expensive operation.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out guys. Very helpful.

Comment: Just wondering. Why, is Math.sqrt(i) expensive, opposed to extracting it into a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

This is quite a nice way of doing it.

Here is some code for you to look at:

```
public void runEratosthenesSieve(int upperBound) {

  int upperBoundSquareRoot = (int) Math.sqrt(upperBound);

  boolean[] isComposite = new boolean[upperBound + 1];

  for (int m = 2; m <= upperBoundSquareRoot; m++) {

        if (!isComposite[m]) {

              System.out.print(m + " ");

              for (int k = m * m; k <= upperBound; k += m)

                    isComposite[k] = true;

        }

  }

  for (int m = upperBoundSquareRoot; m <= upperBound; m++) {

        if (!isComposite[m]) {

              System.out.print(m + " ");

        }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. Just wondering how fast and efficient is this way?

Comment: The complexity of this algorithm is O(n log log n). For your case, this will probably be the most efficient or at least suffice. However, you could look into the Sieve of Atkin as this could be slightly more efficient in some cases with complexity ((N^(1/2))/log N).

Comment: Hey Jurfer just wondering if you can explain the math in this part? for        (int k = m * m; k <= upperBound; k += m)

                    isComposite[k] = true;          I know it marks all the composites as true, but how? Why m*m?

Comment: This is effectively the sieve working through numbers which it knows are definitely not prime. For example if you take a prime number, such as 3 and multiply it by itself (square it), you know for a fact the outcome (in this case: 9), cannot be prime because it is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 1):

Here´s a tuned version of yours.

I did put the check if the number is prime into a seperate method. That´s also a part of the reason why your version did print values multiple times, since if it found out that it has a divisor, then it would print the values. (Also you´r algorythm would print basicly everything despite it beeing prime or not, for example it prints 15 and 27).

The reason why it did print multiple values was, that once you found a divisor it would have printed `i`, but it would continue looping. If it would have found another divisor, it would print `i` again(you can notice that it does not only print prime numbers).

Here is the fixed version of your´s

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(isPrime(2)) {
        System.out.println(2);
    }
    int max_prime = 10000;
    for(int i = 3; i < max_prime; i+=2)
    {
        if(isPrime(i)) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}

private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if(n<=1) return false;
    if(n == 2) return true;
    for(int i = 2;i*i<=n;++i) {
        if(n%i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips and solution, but for the second for loop why did you do i*i ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public class PrimeNumber2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int max_prime = 10000;
        System.out.println(2);
     L: for (int i = 3; i < max_prime; i += 2)
        {
            for (int j = 3, max = (int)Math.sqrt(i); j <= max ; j += 2)
            {
                if(i % j == 0)
                {
                    continue L;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a way using parallelStream

```
System.out.println(2);
IntStream.range(1, 10000000)
         .map(i -> i * 2 + 1)
         .filter(i -> (i & 1) != 0 && IntStream.range(1, (int) (Math.sqrt(i)-1)/2)
                                               .map(j -> j * 2 + 1)
                                               .noneMatching(j -> i % j == 0)
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note: the ranges test the n-th odd number.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int upperBound = 30;
    List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();

    // loop through the numbers one by one
    for (int number = 2; number < upperBound; number++) {
        boolean isPrimeNumber = true;

        // check to see if the number is prime
        for (int j = 2; j < number; j++) {
            if (number % j == 0) {
                isPrimeNumber = false;
                break; // exit the inner for loop
            }
        }

        // print the number if prime
        if (isPrimeNumber) {
            primes.add(number);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The number of prime is: " + primes.size() + ", and they are: " + primes.toString());
}
```

[image]

possible to dupplicate

[get prime numbers and total prime numbers in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508874/get-prime-numbers-and-total-prime-numbers-in-range)

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean isPrimeNumber(int number) {
    for (int i=2; i<=number/2; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `number = 1` should be not prime.